# ¿Cómo comprimir con PowerShell, en WindowsServer 2016?

Tags: powershell, windows-server, windows-server-2016

Buen dia con todos, estoy trabajando con lo que es compresion ntfs en powershell y lo estoy haciendo de esta manera:

```
$folder = Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM CIM_Directory WHERE Name='D:\\prueba'"


$folder.compress()
```

En este caso solo me comprime la carpeta "prueba", deseo que también se compriman los subdirectorios que estan dentro.

Espero que me puedan ayuda, de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar de estar dos formas.

```
Compress-Archive -Path "D:\prueba\*" -Update -DestinationPath "D:\prueba.zip"
```

```
Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory("D:\prueba\", "D:\prueba.zip")
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que necesitas es comprimir archivos utilizando ntfs, podes hacerlo muy fácil desde powershell, pero usando un comando de windows: [compact](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/compact). Para que sea

```
compact /c /s C:\Users\Juan_Pablo\Desktop\logo\prueba\*
```

- /s también comprime los subdirectorios
- /c es para comprimir
- /u es para descomprimir

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]